# How to draw a border on the text within a UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I would like to be able to draw a border around the text within a `UITextField` in Swift, is this possible and if so, how is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using NSAttributedString, which lets you customise text. I'd recommend using a useful program called Attributed String Creator, you can find it on the app store. This lets you create text in an editor and copy and paste the code required to make that text.

**EDIT**:

If you don't want to download the program, here's a snippet of some black-outlined text I made:

```
    // Create the attributed string
var myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"Example Text")

// Declare the fonts
let myStringFont1 = UIFont(name:"Helvetica", size:14.0)

// Declare the paragraph styles
var myStringParaStyle1 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
myStringParaStyle1.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Natural
myStringParaStyle1.tabStops = [NSTextTab(textAlignment: NSTextAlignment.Left, location: 28.000000, options: nil), NSTextTab(textAlignment: NSTextAlignment.Left, location: 56.000000, options: nil), NSTextTab(textAlignment: NSTextAlignment.Left, location: 84.000000, options: nil), NSTextTab(textAlignment: NSTextAlignment.Left, location: 112.000000, options: nil), NSTextTab(textAlignment: NSTextAlignment.Left, location: 140.000000, options: nil), NSTextTab(textAlignment: NSTextAlignment.Left, location: 168.000000, options: nil), NSTextTab(textAlignment: NSTextAlignment.Left, location: 196.000000, options: nil), NSTextTab(textAlignment: NSTextAlignment.Left, location: 224.000000, options: nil), NSTextTab(textAlignment: NSTextAlignment.Left, location: 252.000000, options: nil), NSTextTab(textAlignment: NSTextAlignment.Left, location: 280.000000, options: nil), NSTextTab(textAlignment: NSTextAlignment.Left, location: 308.000000, options: nil), NSTextTab(textAlignment: NSTextAlignment.Left, location: 336.000000, options: nil), ]


// Create the attributes and add them to the string
myString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value:myStringFont1!, range:NSMakeRange(0,12))
myString.addAttribute(NSStrokeWidthAttributeName, value:3, range:NSMakeRange(0,12))
myString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:myStringParaStyle1, range:NSMakeRange(0,12))
```

*EDIT 2*:

Put all that inside this text field delegate function, and change the string used to `textField.text`:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        //Put all that inside here
}
```

Comment: please provide a code snippet with border of the text in black . Thank you

Comment: Im using this code

let memeTextAttributes = [
    NSStrokeColorAttributeName : //TODO: Fill in appropriate UIColor,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : //TODO: Fill in UIColor,
    NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 40)!,
    NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : //TODO: Fill in appropriate Float 
    ]
yourTextField.defaultTextAttributes = memeTextAttributes

But all my coonstraints and other stuffs that i have done in storyboard will be lost for the text due to the  .defaultTextAttribute .

Comment: No cuz the text will be typed by the user and how will you declare myString= NSMutableAttributedString(...) before hand ??